# Capturing output of python code and exporting into a JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a file named phone.py which give me output as(in terminal):

```
+911234567890
+910123321423
```

There can be more number of outputs.

Another file named email.py which produces(in terminal):

```
and@abc.com
bcd@cdc.com
```

or more.

And I have a JSON File whose structure is as follows:

```
{"One":"Some data",
 "two":"Some more data",
 "three":"Even more data"}
```

There can be a many more sections like this.

Now I want the capture the terminal output and also load the existing JSON and finally, have an output as follows (as a JSON file):

```
{Phone:"+911234567890,+910123321423", "Email":"and@abc.com,bcd@cdc.com","Sections":"{"One":"Some data",
 "two":"Some more data",
 "three":Even more data"}"}
```

I tried to capture the output using subprocess module in python and now it is stored in a variable

```
subprocess.run(['python','email.py','filename.txt'], stdout= subprocess.PIPE)
```

output:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['python', 'email_txt.py', 'upload/filename.txt'], returncode=0, stdout=b'abc@xyz.com\nbcd@dcd.com\n')
```

I have a string in which data is stored not I want the desired output through these components.
What can I do or refer to tackle this problem ?

Comment: Include your attempt at capturing the output.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil- Did

Comment: Removing the `bash` tag as it is not an efficient way to construct the required `JSON`

Comment: Producing `"email": ["abc@xyz.com", "bcd@dcd.com"]` would seem like a better way to encode this in JSON.

Comment: Why would you run Python in a subprocess? `import` the script and call its main function from within your own script.  This improves cohesion as well as performance.

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain the stdout from `subprocess.run` simply by `resp.stdout`, where `resp` is the returned object.

Comment: Maybe also mention that the optional argument `universal_newlines=True` will also take care of decoding any output according to the default terminal encoding.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Rishav, you need to assign the output to a variable & then use it to get the related attributes.

[Sample usage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) -

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> out = subprocess.run(["ls", "-l", "/dev/null"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> out.stdout
b'crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Apr  6  2017 /dev/null\n'
```

Comment: This is returned as type "bytes", how do i get it as a string ?

Comment: You could use `out.stdout.decode('utf-8')`, as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/606199/2689986